# Sorting a linked list in C (Selection Sort)

Tags: c

what is better while sorting a linked list, directly swaping the values or changing the address of the next pointer.

I came across many examples using the swaping value technique, but none using the address change mechanism

Method used: Selection Sort

Is there a way to do it via Changing the address of pointers

Answer (score 1):

Swapping pointers is always preferable.  The reason is that with a linked list, the data structure contains arbitrary data and, by necessity, a pointer to the next node.  Therefore, in your swap, copying only a pointer is more efficient than copying a pointer and data.

Answer (score 0):

linked lists are usually swaped based on pointers. This is because each element might be too big for swapping and it can happen that elements in linked list are overloaded.

For example:

```
struct myelement
{
    linked_list ll;
    lot_of_data;
}
```

Swapping pointers enables you to swap any type of elements that are overloaded whit linked list whitout knowing there size.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's possible:

```
struct node {
 int val;
 struct node *next;
};

void sort(struct node **list) {
 if (!*list) return;
 struct node **minadr=list,*cur=*list;
 int min=(*list)->val;
 while (cur) {
  if (cur->val<min) {
   min=cur->val;
   minadr=&(cur->next);
  }
  cur=cur->next;
 }
 if (minadr!=list) {
  cur=*minadr;
  *minadr=*list;
  *list=cur;
 }
 sort(&((*list)->next));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the actual values can be done too. But, there is a chance you might mess up, the list especially if the list is huge or if it has each node has a lot of fields. You might end up swapping a few fields and leaving the rest unchanged causing inconsistency. Its better to use pointers to the nodes to avoid all this and its fairly easy too as asaelr suggested.